# How would you implement an automatic way of the images loading in a pop-up (lightbox/colorbox) window by a click?

Tags: javascript

What I mean is, can we achieve the blogspot.com/Blogger experience where we can add photos to the content (node in Drupal speak) and without any ado (adding `class="colorbox"`, or enclosing the `<img>` element into an `<a>` ), clicking the photo in the post will make it enlarged in a pop-up window, similar to how colorbox functions.

I have visited this question [Configuring Lightbox2 to Pop-Up Images embedded in nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179071/configuring-lightbox2-to-pop-up-images-embedded-in-nodes) and it seems ambiguous to me.

I have a current Drupal 7 site and it's quite annoying that I have to manually enclose the images in a

```
<a class="colorbox colorbox-insert-image" href="..." title=..."> ... </a>
```

every effing time.

Answer (score 0):

You can. As always, there are several ways.

You can implement a Drupal behavior (jQuery script) that finds all images within the content and adds according classes / click callbacks.

Another way would be writing a little custom module implementing a content filter that does the same on your server.

I'm not at a PC right now. But I think you have two viable ideas now to search for. Let me know, if you need further help.